# Split words in textboxes removing whitespaces

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I'm trying to separate the words but there's whitespaces remaining in `FirstName` and `MiddleName`.

See screenshot:
[image: Sample image]

Here's my code:

```
Dim str As String = ListView1.Items(ListView1.SelectedIndices(0)).SubItems(2).Text
Dim splitStr As String() = str.Split(","c)
txtLastName.Text = splitStr(0).ToString()
txtFirstName.Text = splitStr(1).ToString()
txtMiddleInitial.Text = splitStr(2).ToString()
```

Is my code missing something?

Comment: I think you may be after the [String.Trim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove white-space characters from the start and end of a `String` I would use [String.Trim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Removes all leading and trailing white-space characters from the current String object.

To do this in your code simply append `.Trim()` to the end of your `String`:

```
Dim str As String = ListView1.Items(ListView1.SelectedIndices(0)).SubItems(2).Text
Dim splitStr As String() = str.Split(","c)
txtLastName.Text = splitStr(0).ToString().Trim()
txtFirstName.Text = splitStr(1).ToString().Trim()
txtMiddleInitial.Text = splitStr(2).ToString().Trim()
```

As a side note since `splitStr(.)` is already a `String` you don't need to use `ToString()`:

```
txtLastName.Text = splitStr(0).Trim()
txtFirstName.Text = splitStr(1).Trim()
txtMiddleInitial.Text = splitStr(2).Trim()
```

To test, this was my code:

```
Dim str As String = "LOWELL, JOHN, F"
Dim splitStr As String() = str.Split(","c)

TextBox1.Text = splitStr(0)
TextBox2.Text = splitStr(1)
TextBox3.Text = splitStr(2)

TextBox4.Text = splitStr(0).Trim()
TextBox5.Text = splitStr(1).Trim()
TextBox6.Text = splitStr(2).Trim()
```

This is my output:

[image]

The `TextBox` order is the same as the code. You can see where the white-space has been removed from the bottom set using `.Trim()`.

Comment: Thank you sir. I've got it now. Thanks for your help. I thought .ToString makes is suitable for the code.

Comment: @J.Leo please consider accepting the answer if it resolved your issue. Also `.ToString()` isn't necessary in this instance but would be in this; `Dim a As Integer = 1`...`Dim s As String = a.ToString()`

Comment: Yes sir it resolved my issue. So, .ToString() can also convert string. Thank you again.